# Cron Jobs Not Running at all, Working manually

Tags: php, cron

So I have an issue where my cron job isn't running. I've never used cron before so it might just be me not knowing how to set this up properly, but I don't think it is. I set up the cron job in cpanel, and it runs to my main website directory where "test.php" is located.

It works absolutely fine if I manually go to the page(By entering the domain/test. But doesn't work at all with cron, so I know this issue isn't with the function but with the cron. I currently have it set to run every minute, just for testing purposes. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Cron:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php -q /home1/website/public_html/test.php
```

PHP

```
<?php

require("../backend/backend.php");

$id = "4127684511423";

sendChannelMessage($channelid);

?>
```

Comment: If you move to a different directory and then run the script, you'll see that it can't require backend.php, because it's looking relative to the running directory. Change that to an absolute path.

Comment: Read about `__DIR__`

Comment: @aynber Yeah lol I just realised that I had the require wrong. Even though I fixed the require to require("../backend/backend.php"); it still doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: @0stone0 Thank you for your comment, that got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__DIR__` would give the script working directory so when using `require` it would always translate the path correctly

example:

```
<?php
define('DIR', __DIR__);
require_once(DIR.'../backend/backend.php');
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've only just seen this. This solved my issue, thank you!